# How to drag multiple images by extending View in Android?

Tags: android

I am working on drag and drop of images.I developed `MyView` class by extending `View`  and I have overridden `onDraw` method and now I am able to drag single image.

But when it comes to multiple images I am not able to drag the required image. When I try to do it,every image is being dragged.

Here is My Code:

public class Home extends Activity {

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(new MyView(getApplicationContext()));

 }
public static class MyView extends View{
     private Drawable mIcon,mIcon1;
     private TextView tv;
    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mIcon=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    mIcon.setBounds(0,0,mIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(),mIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());

    mIcon1=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);

    mIcon1.setBounds(40,40,150,100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(mPosX,mPosY);
        tv.draw(canvas);
        mIcon.draw(canvas);
        mIcon1.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();   
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     switch(event.getAction())
     {
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = event.getX();
            final float y = event.getY();
            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            break;
        }     
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            final float x = event.getX();
            final float y = event.getY();
            final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
            final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;
            mPosX += dx;
            mPosY += dy;
            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
     }
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please add some code,, But while you are doing so,, have you add all the images to the same view, you must create different instances of MyView each with an image to seperate the dragging operations.